# How can I easily uncouple this slide and lock, wedged to each other, on my office chair?

Tags: furniture

While my hunky husband was lifting the chair up, and my brawny brother pushing the frame down, I kept hitting the top of the slide with a screwdriver, to try to loosen the slide.  But these parts are still wedged too tightly! We ran out of energy and ideas! ***How can we life hack this please?***

[image: Image alt text]

- [Video](https://vimeo.com/497218351)
- [Illustration from this PDF](https://www.stressless.com/en/-/media/stressless/feature/spots/ownerstoolbox/assembly/home-office/assembly-stressless-home-office-chair.pdf)
- [Chair manufacturer's page list these both.](https://www.stressless.com/en/services/owners-toolbox/assembly?stay=1)

Comment: Welcome to [lifehacks.se]! That's not a GIF, it's an MP4, and Stack Exchange doesn't support inlining that - and perhaps rightfully so, since auto-play videos can be very distracting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably because it's a *cam lock* which requires you to *rotate* the slotted part with a screwdriver in order to release the joint instead of swatting it with a hammer.