# How can I smooth and straighten out this wrinkle, on the side of my leather chair?

Tags: furniture

How can I level out this crumple? [This office chair uses animal leather.](https://www.stressless.com/en/services/materials/leather) See the 3 pictures below please. Is it just an air bubble? **I can, but prefer NOT to, [uncouple the black slide and lock](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/26779).**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wrinkle is there by design. And I mean, bad design. And bad manufacture. The easiest thing is to live with it. No matter how bad it looks now, it will look even worse if you try some simple hack.

If you still want to have the problem fixed, contact some local businesses which work with leather, and ask them to do the job.

Note: the repair really depends on the type of leather - natural (from some animal) or "ecological" (plastic).

The other alternative - possibly the best - is to contact the manufacturer / merchant and ask for a replacement.

---

The biggest part of your problem is that there is a hole in the leather. If you just do the simple thing, you will make the leather look straighter, but you will have the original hole visible. How you can make the original hole invisible - beats me. Maybe fill it with noodles and superglue, and then paint it :)

That is why I said that a good specialist might be able to do a better job.

Comment: "local businesses which work with leather" **Examples please? This is natural cowhide leather.** "If you just do the simple thing" **What do you mean? What's "the simple thing"? How exactly can I "make the leather look straighter"???**

Comment: examples of local businesses? Look around your home, and see if there is any company making shoes, clothes, furniture or whatever using leather. They might want to get involved - considering that you need a hack, not something specific for their business.

Comment: simple thing: remove the black thingy (which you do not want to do, but is the only way to fix), straighten the leather, make a new hole, re-attach the black thingy. The original hole will remain visible, of course, as I already said.